# PyCharm not recognizing certain modules

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, ide

Some of the modules I'm trying to import in PyCharm are not recognized (as shown in the picture). The weird thing is that for example, PyCharm is able to recognize 'linkage' from scipy.cluster.hierarchy', but not 'zscore' from 'scipy.stats', meaning that 'scipy' is indeed installed.

I'm using PyCharm 2020.1 and Python 3.7.7

I already tried:

- Uninstalling and installing PyCharm.
- Uninstalling and installing Python 3.7.7.
- Configuring my project interpreter from the start and installing all the packages.
- Using a different version of Python (3.8.2).
- Checking the Interpreter paths.
- Using a virtual environment in the project (venv folder).
- Making sure the interpreter I'm using matches the python interpreter in the Python console settings.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thank you.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTN3V.jpg)  [interpreter paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2RCI.jpg)  [python console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOUqI.jpg)

Comment: Please go to ```File-> Settings->Project -> Python Interpretor``` and post a screenshot of it.   There should be list of all your installed modules. Also are you using venv?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's a big list of packages, so maybe it would be better if I screenshot a specific part you are interested in? 
And I'm not using venv currently, but as I mentioned, when I tried using it, it didn't work also.

Comment: Ok, no need to send screenshoot then, just check are your modules there. And try to reinstall them.

Comment: Already did, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because these modules are installed in the path

> C:\Users\"Username"\AppData\Roaming\Python....

which is not a part of your environment variables. Add this path to the  Environment Variable. For doing that you can follow the instructions [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/). This should probably fix your problem.

This can be seen here: (maybe different in your system)
[image]

Generally, Python is installed in

> C:\Users\"Username"\AppData\Local\Packages\Python....

or

> C:\Program Files\Python....

and only these are added to the path variable.

EDIT:

1. Try doing a clean uninstall of PyCharm (remove the registry entries, left out files related to PyChram, remove the .PyCharm folder in your user directory, etc. maybe using a software) and then reinstall it.
2. Although its very unlikely, but in case you didn't wait for the index to be built when PyCharm opens (and also other background processes that start up), wait for them and then try again.
3. Also, try this: go to Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter. In the list that appears, find the library you are missing. If the name is not there, click on the + button and install it through PyChram, else uninstall and install it through the same method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @tanish. But I don't have a folder named 'Python' under 'Roaming'. Besides, I checked my path again and Python is configured there as 'C:\Users\Yoni Itzhak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37'.
So this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try updating these libraries like I did and check where they are installed. If they are not installed in the Local folder, then try adding their paths to the PATH environment variables.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it too and found out they are installed in the Local folder, where the PATH is configured.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. I had to uninstall PyCharm and also **delete its caches** from my computer (which are not deleted during the uninstall). 
After I installed PyCharm again, it worked.